# Equivalent syntax in SQL Server from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Is there any equivalent syntax in SQL Server similar to mysql

```
REPLACE INTO
```

[OR]

```
INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Ex. query in `MySQL`

```
insert INTO supply_data values('1','be','dept','loc','team',4,2015,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) on duplicate key update pid=pid and be=be
```

I am trying to convert this into T-SQL

Comment: Yes it is called [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb510625.aspx)

```
MERGE supply_data AS t
    USING (SELECT '1','be','dept','loc', ...) AS s (pid, be, val_1, val_2, ...)
    ON (t.pid = s.pid and t.be = s.be)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET clm_1 = val_1, clm_2 = s.val_2, ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (pid, be, clm_1, clm_2, ...)
    VALUES (pid, be, val_1, val_2, ...)
```

Try this;

```
MERGE supply_data AS t 
    USING (
        SELECT 1, 'be','dept','loc','team', 2016,
        1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1
    ) 
    AS s (
        pid, be, dept, location, team, aopyr,
        jansupply, febsupply, marsupply, aprsupply, 
        maysupply, junsupply, julsupply, augsupply,
        sepsupply, octsupply, novsupply, decsupply
    )
    ON (
        t.pid = s.pid and t.be = s.be and 
        t.location=s.location and t.team=s.team and 
        t.aopyr=s.aopyr
    ) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
        jansupply = s.jansupply, febsupply = s.febsupply, 
        marsupply = s.marsupply, aprsupply = s.aprsupply,  
        maysupply = s.maysupply, junsupply = s.junsupply, 
        julsupply = s.julsupply, augsupply = s.augsupply, 
        sepsupply = s.sepsupply, octsupply = s.octsupply, 
        novsupply = s.novsupply, decsupply = s.decsupply  
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (
        pid, be, dept, location, team, aopyr,
        jansupply, febsupply, marsupply, aprsupply, 
        maysupply, junsupply, julsupply, augsupply,
        sepsupply, octsupply, novsupply, decsupply
    ) 
    VALUES (
        s.pid, s.be, s.dept, s.location, s.team, s.aopyr,
        s.jansupply, s.febsupply, s.marsupply, s.aprsupply, 
        s.maysupply, s.junsupply, s.julsupply, s.augsupply,
        s.sepsupply, s.octsupply, s.novsupply, s. decsupply
    )
```

Comment: Thanks I am trying this. But dont know why I am getting this error; Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi - Did you remove the `, ...` at the end

Comment: MERGE supply_data AS t 
USING (SELECT pid, be,dept,location,team,aopyr,jansupply,febsupply,marsupply,aprsupply,
maysupply,junsupply,julsupply,augsupply,sepsupply,octsupply,novsupply,decsupply) AS s 
(pid, be,dept,location,team,aopyr,jansupply,febsupply,marsupply,aprsupply,
maysupply,junsupply,julsupply,augsupply,sepsupply,octsupply,novsupply,decsupply)
ON (t.pid = s.pid and t.be = s.be and t.location=s.location and t.team=s.team and t.aopyr=s.aopyr)
WHEN MATCHED THEN

Comment: UPDATE SET jansupply='1',febsupply='1',marsupply='1',aprsupply='1',
maysupply='1',junsupply='1',julsupply='1',augsupply='1',sepsupply='1',octsupply='1',
novsupply='1',decsupply='1'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (pid, be,dept,location,team,aopyr,jansupply,febsupply,marsupply,aprsupply,
maysupply,junsupply,julsupply,augsupply,sepsupply,octsupply,novsupply,decsupply)
VALUES (1, 'be','dept','loc','team',2016,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

Comment: Above two comments I am trying; This is the error I am getting; Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: Where are the values.... `using (select '1','be','dept','loc','team'......) as s(pid, be,dept,location,team......)`

Comment: MERGE supply_data AS t 
USING (SELECT 1, 'be','dept','loc','team',2016,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) AS s 
(pid, be,dept,location,team,aopyr,jansupply,febsupply,marsupply,aprsupply,
maysupply,junsupply,julsupply,augsupply,sepsupply,octsupply,novsupply,decsupply)
ON (t.pid = s.pid and t.be = s.be and t.location=s.location and t.team=s.team and t.aopyr=s.aopyr)
WHEN MATCHED THEN

Comment: UPDATE SET jansupply='1',febsupply='1',marsupply='1',aprsupply='1',
maysupply='1',junsupply='1',julsupply='1',augsupply='1',sepsupply='1',octsupply='1',
novsupply='1',decsupply='1'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (pid, be,dept,location,team,aopyr,jansupply,febsupply,marsupply,aprsupply,
maysupply,junsupply,julsupply,augsupply,sepsupply,octsupply,novsupply,decsupply)
VALUES (1, 'be','dept','loc','team',2016,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

Comment: @Praveen I used your updated answer but still same error I am getting here